# Simple Analytical Function

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

Why is the following not a SAF? It applies the exponent a finite numer of times.

[image]

Which rule is it violating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) The derivative is not well defined at the steps:

[image]

Comment: rule b) says "has a finite # of roots".  The function does have a finite # of roots (0).

Comment: Ooops... fixed.